# Conditional formatting on whether something is a formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

Is there a way, in Google Sheets, to have conditional formatting of some sort, to change the background color of a cell based on whether the cell contains a formula or a plain value?

Answer (score 1):

- red color for not formula & not empty:

  ```
  =(NOT(ISFORMULA(B1)))*(B1<>"")
  ```

  [image: 0]

---

- yellow color for the formula detection:

  ```
  =ISFORMULA(B1)
  ```

  [image: 0]

---

- bonus fact - showing a formula as text string:

  ```
  =FORMULATEXT(B2)
  ```

  [image: 0]